# android sqlite always get 2017 on query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

For an Android pedometer project for school I used SQLite following a tutorial. I have only one table containing the number of steps made by day (as a string).
The problem is, whichever day I call, it gets me 2017 as the steps number. So I suppose it has something to do with the date I also get.

Here is the class that handle the database logic :

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String TAG = "DatabaseHandler";

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "statsManager";

    // Table name
    private static final String DAILY_STATS_TABLE = "dailyStats";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_DAY = "day";
    private static final String KEY_STEPS = "steps";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(TAG, "::onCreate");
        String CREATE_STAT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DAILY_STATS_TABLE +                  "(" + KEY_DAY + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_STEPS + " INTEGER" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_STAT_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int   newVersion) {
        Log.d(TAG, "::onUpgrade");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DAILY_STATS_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addContact(DailyStat dailyStat) {
        Log.d(TAG, "::addContact");
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_DAY, dailyStat.getFormattedDate());
        Log.d(TAG, "trying to insert date : " + dailyStat.getFormattedDate());
        values.put(KEY_STEPS, dailyStat.get_steps());
        Log.d(TAG, "trying to insert steps : " + dailyStat.get_steps());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(DAILY_STATS_TABLE, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public DailyStat getDailyStat(String day) throws ParseException, NullPointerException {
        Log.d(TAG, "::getDailyStat");
        Log.i(TAG, "looking for : " + String.valueOf(day));
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(DAILY_STATS_TABLE,
                            new String[] {KEY_DAY, KEY_STEPS},
                            KEY_DAY + "=?",
                            new String[] {day},
                            null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        Log.i(TAG, cursor.toString());
        DailyStat result = null;
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "got : " + cursor.getString(0) + " and " + cursor.getInt(0));
            result = new DailyStat(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getInt(0));
        } catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "no stats for this day.");
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }

// other methods
```

I tested my app on my Galaxy S4 mini, so I can't easily see what the database looks like.
And I heard that you can't see the requests formed with insert() and query() methods.

Anybody has an idea of what is wrong ?

Comment: don't you think , it should be `cursor.getString(0), cursor.getInt(1)`

Comment: You actually can easily see the database... Try Stetho library. Not that that fixes the typo

Comment: It is possible, looking at the tutorial I assumed that, for example, if I had a table with one INT column as the last column, it would be accessed through cursor.getInt(0) since it is the first int of the table.

Comment: No, the number isn't the first type of column. It is just the column index.

Comment: ok, thank you for your advices, I'll try these this evening. I'll keep you in touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is that the you do no get the steps from the database. Instead you get part of the date.

That is the following two lines

```
        Log.d(TAG, "got : " + cursor.getString(0) + " and " + cursor.getInt(0));
        result = new DailyStat(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getInt(0));
```

Should be :-

```
        Log.d(TAG, "got : " + cursor.getString(0) + " and " + cursor.getInt(1));
        result = new DailyStat(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getInt(1));
```

i.e. Index **1** (the 2nd column **steps**) instead of Index **0** (the 1st column).

Below is code that you may wish to consider adopting that a) fixes the issue and introduces what could be more flexible techniques and also provides a quick get around for not being able to see the data in the database.

So perhaps the following will be of use:-

1) My simple **DailyStats** class (**NOTE this was used for testing purposes, it's not intended to be used but has been included so you have a full picture**) :-

```
public class DailyStat {

    private String mDate;
    private int mSteps;

    public DailyStat(String date, int steps) {
        mDate = date;
        mSteps = steps;
    }

    public String getFormattedDate() {
        return mDate;
    }

    public int get_steps() {
        return mSteps;
    }
}
```

2) The changed/new **DBHelper** methods:-

```
        public DailyStat getDailyStat(String day) throws ParseException, NullPointerException {

            DailyStat result = null;
            Log.d(TAG, "::getDailyStat");
            //Log.i(TAG, "looking for : " + String.valueOf(day));
            Log.i(TAG, "looking for : " + day);
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query(DAILY_STATS_TABLE,
                    new String[] {KEY_DAY, KEY_STEPS},
                    KEY_DAY + "=?",
                    new String[] {day},
                    null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                //Log.d(TAG, "got : " + cursor.getString(0) + " and " + cursor.getInt(0));
                Log.d(TAG, "got : " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DAY))
                        + " and "
                        + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_STEPS))
                );

                //result = new DailyStat(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getInt(0));
                result = new DailyStat(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DAY)),
                        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_STEPS))
                );
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "no stats for this day.");
            }
            cursor.close();
            return result;
        }

        public Cursor getAllStats() {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            return db.query(DAILY_STATS_TABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        }

        public void logAllStats(Cursor cursor) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Row " + Integer.toString(cursor.getPosition()));
                for (int i =0; i < cursor.getColumnCount();i++) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "\tColumn=" + cursor.getColumnName(i) +
                            " Value=" + cursor.getString(i)
                    );
                }
            }
        }
```

Note! basically all that I've done in `getDailyStat` is utilise `cursor.getCount` instead of checking for a null cursor (*a cursor is not null id 0 rows are returned*), and used `cursor.getColumnIndex(columnname)`, the latter resolving the incorrect index (as per the first comment).

`getAllStats` and `logAllStats` are just added as a quick get around of the issue of not being able to see the database.

3) The invoking activities code used for testing (NOTE I've called class **DatabaseHandler** **StepsDBHelper** fro my convenience) :-

```
            //DailyStat ds = new DailyStat("21/03/2017",10); used for 1st run
            //DailyStat ds = new DailyStat("21/03/2016",10); used for 2nd run

            StepsDBHelper sdbhlp = new StepsDBHelper(this);
            //sdbhlp.addContact(ds); used for 1st and then 2nd run
            DailyStat ds1 = sdbhlp.getDailyStat("21/03/2016");
            Log.d("DS1","Day=" + ds1.getFormattedDate() + " Steps=" + Integer.toString(ds1.get_steps()));
            DailyStat ds2 = sdbhlp.getDailyStat("21/03/2017");
            Log.d("DS2","Day=" + ds2.getFormattedDate() + " Steps=" + Integer.toString(ds2.get_steps()));
            // using 21/03/2018 returns null DailyStats object
            DailyStat ds3 = sdbhlp.getDailyStat("21/03/2018");
            if (ds3 == null) {
                Log.d("DS3","NULL");
            } else {
                Log.d("DS3","Day=" + ds3.getFormattedDate() + " Steps=" + Integer.toString(ds3.get_steps()));
            }
            sdbhlp.logAllStats(sdbhlp.getAllStats());
```

Finally the output from after the first two runs that added the data (as per comments) :-

```
07-19 07:56:34.190 3981-3981/? D/DatabaseHandler: ::getDailyStat
07-19 07:56:34.190 3981-3981/? I/DatabaseHandler: looking for : 21/03/2016
07-19 07:56:34.191 3981-3981/? D/DatabaseHandler: got : 21/03/2016 and 10
07-19 07:56:34.191 3981-3981/? D/DS1: Day=21/03/2016 Steps=10
07-19 07:56:34.191 3981-3981/? D/DatabaseHandler: ::getDailyStat
07-19 07:56:34.191 3981-3981/? I/DatabaseHandler: looking for : 21/03/2017
07-19 07:56:34.191 3981-3981/? D/DatabaseHandler: got : 21/03/2017 and 10
07-19 07:56:34.191 3981-3981/? D/DS2: Day=21/03/2017 Steps=10
07-19 07:56:34.191 3981-3981/? D/DatabaseHandler: ::getDailyStat
07-19 07:56:34.191 3981-3981/? I/DatabaseHandler: looking for : 21/03/2018
07-19 07:56:34.194 3981-3981/? I/DatabaseHandler: no stats for this day.
07-19 07:56:34.195 3981-3981/? D/DS3: NULL
07-19 07:56:34.195 3981-3981/? D/DatabaseHandler: Row 0
07-19 07:56:34.195 3981-3981/? D/DatabaseHandler:   Column=day Value=21/03/2017
07-19 07:56:34.195 3981-3981/? D/DatabaseHandler:   Column=steps Value=10
07-19 07:56:34.195 3981-3981/? D/DatabaseHandler: Row 1
07-19 07:56:34.195 3981-3981/? D/DatabaseHandler:   Column=day Value=21/03/2016
07-19 07:56:34.195 3981-3981/? D/DatabaseHandler:   Column=steps Value=10
```

Instead of 2017 (21 with the date format I used) the number of steps is as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer.
Yesterday evening, following the comments I eplaced .getInt(0) with getInt(1) and it worked.
But seeing your post I think I'll correct it again and use cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY) it seems to be a better practice.